# Do taxi drivers in Rio give receipts?

Tags: transportation, taxis, rio-de-janeiro

On a cab trip in Rio, for instance from the airport to a hotel, can I pay in cash and ask the driver to give me a receipt (i.e. can I expect that he/she will comply)?

Otherwise, would paying by card help me obtain a receipt (if there are drivers who accept it)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They started to migrate to a new system 2 years ago, most of the drivers give you a receipt if you ask for it.

And yes, most of the cabs accept credit / debit card.

Just in case, If you gonna take it from the Airport, when you take your bag and go to the main hall, you gonna see a hugeeeeee line, this line is for the cabs.. I would mind to check before where you are going. because most of the times they have a board on the wall showing the prices for different neighborhoods according to the distance!

They also have a bus, if you prefer, with air conditioning and wi-fi.

Answer (score 2):

Uber is [now available in Rio](https://www.uber.com/cities/rio-de-janeiro/), so you can use them instead. Receipts are automatically sent out by email and are also available online for future downloading:

[image: uber fare breakdown]